# Why does gcc infer the type from the callback function's last argument here?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make a template function that takes a pointer to a function with any number of inputs, except it must have an int as its last input. Then the template function should call this function with the provided arguments and five as the last argument. The code will make it clear:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class ... B>
void passFive(A (*f)(B ..., int n), B ... x) {
        f(x ..., 5);
}

void printStrAndInt(const char *s, int n) {
        std::cout << s << " " << n << "\n";
}

int main() {
        passFive(&printStrAndInt, "pineapple");
        return 0;
}
```

However, gcc doesn't like this and gives me an error along with notes:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘passFive(void (*)(const char*, int), const char [10])’
  passFive(&printStrAndInt, "pineapple");
                                       ^
test.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class A, class ... B> void passFive(A (*)(B ..., int), B ...)
 void passFive(A (*f)(B ..., int n), B ... x) {
      ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:14:39: note:   mismatched types ‘int’ and ‘const char*’
  passFive(&printStrAndInt, "pineapple");
```

So it's inferring the type for B once as a const char * (as expected), but also once as the second argument of printStrAndInt (I'm certain of this because it's the same with other data types besides int). As a side note, it works just fine if I move the int to the front like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class ... B>
void passFive(A (*f)(int n, B ...), B ... x) {
        f(5, x ...);
}

void printStrAndInt(int n, const char *s) {
        std::cout << s << " " << n << "\n";
}

int main() {
        passFive(&printStrAndInt, "pineapple");
        return 0;
}
```

This is not an option for my final solution though. What I would like to know is why it's inferring the type in such an unexpected manner and how I should fix this.

Comment: Seems like `B` is being deduced as `const char*, int`, so it's expecting a function that takes `const char*, int, int`. Works fine in clang, so it might be a gcc bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: a variadic list of template parameters can be **deduced** only when in the last position.

Take also in count that, when isn't in last position, is deduced empty.

So, from

```
template<class A, class ... B>
void passFive(A (*f)(B ..., int n), B ... x) {
        f(x ..., 5);
}
```

and the call

```
passFive(&printStrAndInt, "pineapple");
```

the variadic `B...` list has to be deduced from `f` signature as empy (`B...` isn't in last position, followed by `int`) and `char const *` (or maybe `char const [10]`) from `"pineapple"`.

To avoid this, you can deduce two different lists and impose (SFINAE or a `static_assert()`) that the second variadic list is as the first one, adding `int`.

I mean (SFINAE way) something as

```
template <typename A, typename ... Bs, typename ... Cs>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::tuple<Bs...>,
                                std::tuple<Cs..., int>>>
   passFive(A (*f)(Bs ...), Cs ... x)
 { f(x ..., 5); }
```

Not a perfect solution: as in your original code, it's a problem if the `f` function wait for (by example) a `long` and in the `x...` arguments you pass a `int`.

Should be better check if `Cs...` types (plus an `int`) are not equals but convertible to the `Bs...`. But (given the last `int`) I don't see a simple and elegant way to do it (without developing an helper class).